# Changing CloudKit Production Database

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Version 1.0 of my app is in the App Store, and I there are some changes I'd like to make for version 1.1 that would involve adding a few fields to a record type in my CloudKit database. I know that I cannot make changes directly to the Production version of my database. Rather, I have to change the Development version and then re-deploy to Production. I have never done this before, so I have a few concerns, especially since my app is currently live in the App Store.

Most importantly, will re-deploying delete all the records currently in the Production database?

Please only answer this question if you have tried re-deploying from Development to Production with CloudKit before. I really don't want to botch this up for my current users! Thanks in advance!